# Reading Character Array from Shared class in KotlinMultiPlatform (KMM)

Tags: swift, kotlin, nsmutablearray, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

How can I properly read the data from a mutable array in Swift from a Kotlin Module?
**Kotlin Shared Module:**

```
data class Tape(private val capacity: Int) {
        val reel: MutableList<Char>
        ...
}
```

**Swift:**

```
tape.reel.compactMap({ $0 as? Character } // leads to nothing in the array
```

Comment: `Char` in Kotlin is a "16-bit Unicode character", so strictly speaking the equivalent in Swift will be `UInt16`, but you can even start from just `Int`.

Comment: This won't work because `Character` is a swift struct, so kotlin native can't generate it. You can check the type of the variable using `type(of: $0)`: in my case I got some `Shared_kobjcc0`. This is clearly not what I expected: it had to be some subclass of `NSNumber`, since you can't put a regular `Int` inside `NSArray`. I suggest you [create a problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) on the JetBrains issue tracker.

Comment: For now you can store it as ints mayally

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, yes I think that will be my work around for now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Char will be mapped as `UInt16`

One option might be to map your char list to a string in Kotlin:

```
val reel: String
```

Then on the `Swift` side work with it as a `String`